# slope of correlation coefficient affected by independent variable?

Tags: r, regression, correlation, multivariate-analysis

I am interested in testing if the correlation coefficient between 2 dependent variables is significantly affected by an independent variable (which has two levels). I don't think calculating a partial correlation is what I want to do because I don't want to exclude the effect of the independent variable. What I did was to calculate the correlation coefficients independently for each subset of data corresponding to each level of the independent variable and then compared the correlation coefficients using paired.r. I don't know if this is the better way, it seems like there should be a way to estimate the effect of the independent variable within one statistic. Note I am doing this test within each subject.

Any input would be much appreciated!

Comment: Duplicate is here:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/203494/can-i-predict-a-correlation/368228#368228